# What is the correct MySQL syntax for a Trigger with a conditional?

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

Any help would be well received. :)

Scenario: I have a MySql table 'artworkjobs_proudction'. I'm trying to create a trigger in PHPMyAdmin to set a date once certain fields in the table have met specific conditions. Since it is multiple conditions it seems like an IF conditional is the way to go. Below is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `createProductionScheduleDate` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `artworkjobs_production` 
FOR EACH ROW 
IF ((OLD.ArtworkStatus = 'Approved' OR NEW.ArtworkStatus = 'Approved')
  AND (OLD.isCompleted is NULL OR NEW.isCompleted is NULL)
  AND (OLD.isCompleted = 'N' OR NEW.isCompleted = 'N')
  AND (OLD.printDueDate <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR NEW.printDueDate <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
  AND (length(OLD.invoiceNumber) > 0) OR (length(NEW.invoiceNumber) > 0)
  AND (OLD.importance > 0) OR NEW.importance > 0) AND (OLD.quantity > 0 OR NEW.quantity > 0) 
THEN SET originalProductionDueDate = now()
END IF;
```

The error I'm receiving is:

> One or more errors have occured while processing your request:
>   The following query has failed: *`<SQL query as stated above>`*
>
> **MySQL said: #1193 - Unknown system variable 
>   'originalProductionDueDate'**

`originalProductionDueDate` is a correct field however. :(

`createProductionScheduleDate` is the name of the trigger, not of a table.
The table is `artworkjobs_production`. Which I defined here:

```
CREATE TRIGGER createProductionScheduleDate 
       AFTER UPDATE ON artworkjobs_production
```

Comment: Please add the definition of the table `createProductionScheduleDate`.

Comment: @FDavidov That is the name of the Trigger not the table. The table is artworkjobs_production. Which I defined here:                                    `CREATE TRIGGER createProductionScheduleDate
AFTER UPDATE ON artworkjobs_production `

Comment: OOPSS!!! Of course!!! Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the value of a column in the row that spawned the trigger, use

```
SET NEW.originalProductionDueDate = now();
```

But you can't change `NEW.<column>` values in an AFTER trigger. The row has already been updated by then. You must do it in a BEFORE trigger.

Comment: Thanks testing now.

Comment: That was the problem. I was thinking about it backwards thinking that the row update would occur after the other items were satisfied. Makes perfect sense to me now!